# HTACCESS 404 error not working properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**The problem:**

> The requested URL /welcome.php was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Here it goes:

- When I go to www.mysite.com/page it works fine, it also works if I go to mysite.com/404
- But, when I misspell something and go to www.mysite.com/pag (instead of 'page') I'll get the above error.

I'm also using PHP in my index file (welcome.php) to determine the `$_GET` value and dynamically display the correct page. It may have something to do with this.

Test site: http://mrobertsdesign.ca/home (you can see the error at http://mrobertsdesign.ca/hom)

I've looked everywhere for answers, been at this for the past 12 hours just trying to figure out why it isn't working. The bottom line is that I'm not sure what's causing the issue... All help is appreciated!

*Any ideas??*

---

**My .htaccess file is:**

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 http://mrobertsdesign.ca/404

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mrobertsdesign\.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mrobertsdesign.ca/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ welcome.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ welcome.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC]

DirectoryIndex comingsoon.php welcome.php
```

---

**My index file is (welcome.php):**

```
<?php 

    $web_url = "http://mrobertsdesign.ca";

    $path = '';
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $pages = array('home','about','work','contact','404');

    if ((basename($_SERVER['__FILE__'])) == 'welcome.php'){
        if (!empty($page)) {
            $url = '/' . $page;
        } else {
            $page = 'home';
            $url = '/' . $page;
        }
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, 301); exit();
    }
    if (!empty($page)) {
        if(in_array($page,$pages)) {
            if (!empty($category)) {
                $path = $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page;
            } else {
                $path = 'content_' . $page;
            }
        }else {
            $page = '404';
            $url = '/' . $page;
            header('Location: ' . $url, true, 404); exit();
        }
    }
    else {
        $page = 'home';
        $path = 'content_' . $page;
    }

              if($page == 'home'){
                    // stuff for home here
        }else if($page == 'about'){ 
                    $page_title = "About"; 
        }else if($page == 'work'){ 
                    $page_title = "Work"; 
        }else if($page == 'contact'){ 
                    $page_title = "Contact"; 
        }else if($page == '404'){ 
                    $page_title = "Oops! (404)"; 
        }
        $page_class = 'page-' . $page;

    // Page Start

    include('includes/header.php');
    include('includes/' . $path . '.php');
    include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

When changing:

```
    else {
        $page = 'home';
        $url = '/' . $page;
    }
```

To this:

```
    else {
        http_response_code(404); exit; 
    }
```

The error changes to an internal server error for both welcome.php & the 404 error page:

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator, cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>   Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

---

**More info that I've observed:**

- My .htaccess file is rewriting values such as `/welcome.php?page=about` to `/about` and `/welcome.php?category=about&page=me` to `/about/me`, so if I go to `/about` it will go to the about page (and there is no /about/me or any second level of pages at all right now any ways).
- If I misspell that and go to `/abou` or `/anything-here` or `/anything-here/anything-here-too` it displays the error saying that it can't find both my index (welcome.php) and my 404 error page.
- However, if I go to `/welcome.php?page=abo` (instead of `about`, anything that isn't a real page) it displays my 404 error page.
- If I go to `/any-page.fileextention` (eg. /about.php - which doesn't actually exist) it will display the 404 error page, also if I go to `/one/two/three` it will also display the 404 error page.
- If you go to `/welcome.php` (my index page) it will show the correct page, and if you take out part of the file extension like `/welcome.ph` it will display the 404 error page. If you go to the 404 error page it also displays correctly at `/404`.

The error seems to be fired when a file is being treated as a file system (eg. `/about` compared to `/about.php` or `/welcome.php?page=about` or `/welcome.php?page=abo`) for up to two levels in (eg. `/about` and `/about/me`).

In `/welcome.php?page=mypage`, the address literally already points to `/welcome.php`, but in `/about` the address is just a file system that the .htaccess file is supposed to interpret as the `$_GET` value for my `/welcome.php` page, which works when the `$_GET` value is a real value, but when it's not it comes back as an error and throws everything off.

The issue isn't even the error document at this point, it's that it can't find `/welcome.php` and `/404` when the address is read as a file system with incorrect `$_GET` values... It's not trying to find `/abou/welcome.php` because there is a file extension and would be ultimately thrown to the real 404 page, and it's not trying to go to `/abou/404` because in my .htaccess file I've provided the full path to my 404 page at `http://mrobertsdesign.ca/404`. This is where I'm lost.

- How does stackoverflow achieve what it's doing with it's .htaccess file where you can delete part of the url and it will try to either fill it in with the closest resembling url or throw a 404 error page?

---

**The answer!**

As `@Phil_1984_` stated, the following line was conflicting with the `ErrorDocument` request, which caused the 404 not found error for my `/welcome.php` page and `ErrorDocument` request itself:

```
    else {
        $page = 'home';
        $url = '/' . $page;
    }
```

His initial idea was to change the line to the following:

```
    else {
        http_response_code(404); exit; 
    }
```

Which got me thinking, I already have the dynamic layout setup, I can just return the `$_GET` value to the page instead of trying to redirect the whole page to the 404 page - which it turns out is what was causing the issue.

The solution was, instead of trying to redirect the whole page (technically back on itself since the whole site is built up of this PHP script and a series of includes) to the 404 page, to just turn the value of `$_GET` back to `$path` so that the include file `include('includes/' . $path . '.php');` would read it and just include the 404 document into the page (as it would be doing any ways, only difference is that the url doesn't change).

```
    else {
        $page = '404';
        $path = 'content_' . $page;
    }
```

Comment: You could probably do with some `L` (**L**ast) rewrite rule flags. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Comment: I believe you want your ErrorDocument to refer to a file in the context of your filesystem.

Comment: @JoshuaChavanne yes, although that is the 404 page, /404 is the same as /welcome.php?page=404

Comment: @Phil I'm not too good with this htaccess stuff lol, where could I add those? If you have any time to help me out that would be awesome

Comment: @Phil_1984_ I'm not following you my friend... my htaccess mostly works, my PHP code works perfectly fine as far as I know, there's just an error that's causing something to go off relating to my rewrite rules and I'm trying to figure out what's causing that. I could be wrong, at this stage I'm lost which is why I'm on here haha

Comment: Sorry, I misread your htaccess file.  It looks fine actually.  I am getting error 500 now.  Can you check your apache error.log for the problem?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ whoops, I was messing with the htaccess and forgot to change it back to the one in the question, it's back to the one in the question now! Thanks for taking a look. Also, I can't access the apache error log, I'm on a shared hosting package, any work around?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ I've added some observations to help narrow it down at the bottom of the question! I hope that helps you. I know it's the rewrite rules, just not sure why!

Comment: It's a long shot but can you try changing line 28 of your welcome.php file to just http_response_code(404); exit;  I think perhaps apache is getting confused when you send back both a 404 response from php as well as the location of the 404 page.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ done, and updated a blurb in my answer under the php code to reflect the result. Interestingly, it shows an internal server error for both the page it's trying to show and additionally for the ErrorDocument request

Comment: No I think you changed the wrong line.  I meant the line with "header('Location: ' . $url, true, 404); exit();"

Comment: @Phil_1984_ you were on to something, I did figure out the problem and it was with that line in the PHP - it seemed to be conflicting with the ErrorDocument request! Adding the line you suggested didn't work but essentially you had the right idea. The answer was to change that else statement to: else { $page = '404'; $path = 'content_' . $page; }. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you just wanted a 404 rewrite you could have done that by using ErrorDocument 404 /welcome.php?page=404 but i thought you wanted a proper 302 redirect to the 404 page. Glad you got it figured out but i don't understand enough of what problem you fixed. You changed a different line then in my comment and i don't understand how your change fixed the problem.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ all of my pages are technically includes under the welcome.php, the problem was that the 404 page wasnt showing and that error was coming up, I did change the samr line you suggested ( header('Location: ' . $url, true, 404); exit(); ), that was conflicting eith things I guess, so you were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer!**

As `@Phil_1984_` stated, the following line was conflicting with the `ErrorDocument` request, which caused the 404 not found error for my `/welcome.php` page and `ErrorDocument` request itself:

```
    else {
        $page = 'home';
        $url = '/' . $page;
    }
```

His initial idea was to change the line to the following, which didn't work for me (through a 500 error):

```
    else {
        http_response_code(404); exit; 
    }
```

Which got me thinking, I already have the dynamic layout setup, I can just return the `$_GET` value to the page instead of trying to redirect the whole page to the 404 page - which it turns out is what was causing the issue.

The solution was, instead of trying to redirect the whole page (technically back on itself since the whole site is built up of this PHP script and a series of includes) to the 404 page, to just turn the value of `$_GET` back to `$path` so that the include file `include('includes/' . $path . '.php');` would read it and just include the 404 document into the page (as it would be doing any ways, only difference is that the url doesn't change).

```
    else {
        $page = '404';
        $path = 'content_' . $page;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Apache Docs:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html

Make sure the path is correct and AllowOverride is enabled.

Comment: I believe the paths are correct, it's a direct link to the 404 page which works when I go to it directly, just not when htaccess is looking for it - it's the same with my index file (welcome.php), it works, it only can't find it when the GET value of "/welcome.php?page=" is not a real page. When I remove all the mod_rewrite rules the error document actually works fine!

Comment: Maybe write a rule in welcome.php to check the page get variable and if that 'page' does not exist display a message or redirect to the other 404?

Comment: Feel free to show some of the source for welcome.php - but I actually think the FallbackResource is maybe what you are looking for.  As it seems to assume that it is using welcome.php as the directories' fallback index, and if you don't have a way of handling 404s in the welcome.php file it is defaulting to having it handled on the filesystem.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#FallbackResource

Comment: I've added my source for the welcome.php, which is my index page, however the first line in the error is `The requested URL /welcome.php was not found on this server.`, so the problem can't be the fallback, it all works fine without the rewrite on

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for commenting and trying to help!