# Why 404 page is not showing using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using following .htaccess code to showing error message using 2 php page called `404.php` and `not-found.php` when page is not found in my server. But unfortunately it's not working. It's should be show 404.php or not-found.php page if page is not found.

**.htaccess code :**

```
Options -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?:zones/)?update/(\w+)/?$ update.php?z=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516781/htaccess-404-error-not-working-properly?rq=1

Comment: But the code should be work, I don't know why it's not working !

Comment: Did you check apache log for any errors? Do you have `not-found.php` and `404.php` in your root folder? Can you access them `http://url/404.php`?

Comment: Are you sure your rewrite rules do not brake it?

Comment: Well, It's working now if enter full url : http://localhost/aponit/dev/404.php

Comment: `/aponit/dev/404.php` vs `/404.php` huge difference ;)

Comment: Yes but found another issue :(

Comment: if I enter this url : http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones it's open the correct file with all stylesheet but if I enter this url : http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/ (forward slash at the end) then it's broken the page. I mean stylesheet is not working. Can I show error message then ?

Comment: You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/aponit/dev/" />` to fix css/js etc not working.